# Why does the NOT operator (!) not work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I was writing code for an algorithm challenge and it didn't seem to work for some reason. I realized, I was writing something like,

```
var repeat = false;
if (!repeat){
   counter++;
}
```

This didn't seem to work. When I changed the code to,

```
var repeat = false;
if (repeat == false){
   counter++;
}
```

it worked. Why is this? Doesn't the '!repeat' automatically mean 'repeat == false'?

Comment: "Doesn't the '!repeat' automatically mean 'repeat == false'" - nope. It means "negate repeat". It doesn't imply any comparison operators.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `because !false equals true` and? How is that related to the question?

Comment: OP: Your both snippets behave exactly the same.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Actually with `var repeat = false;` it does imply it and OP is right.

Comment: @freakish: what do you mean? Negation is negation. It is not comparison.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev In the context of `if` statement of course. Besides these 2 statements `!repeat` and `repeat == false` return the same value assuming `var repeat = false`.

Comment: @freakish: yes, these __concrete__ examples __behave__ the same. Still, negation by itself never means comparison ("Doesn't the '!repeat' automatically mean 'repeat == false'?")

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Never? Are you sure about that? There are only 3 objects (that I found out) for which `!repeat` is not the same as `repeat == false` and that is: `[], null, undefined`. Don't use such strong words. I'd say it's almost always the same (and yes, this actually shows how retarded js is).

Comment: @freakish: you're confusing apparent similarity of outputs with meaning of the expressions. Those are two different things, negation and comparison. And yes, it's never. RE "it's almost always the same" - 25% chance of producing correct result on falsey values is far from "almost always". And JFYI, `[]` is truthy.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev What does "meaning of the expression" mean? It's exactly how it is evaluated. There is no other meaning. There is no 25% chance of producing correct result. There is 0% chance of producing an incorrect result assuming there is an infinite possible different objects in JS (cause it fails only for literally 3 objects). And what truthyness of `[]` has to do with anything? Who said we are testing falsy values? It is you who wanted to generalize the concept.

Comment: Alright, I think I'm done here.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me in both cases

```
var repeat = false;
var counter = 0;

if (!repeat){
   counter++;
}

console.log('Counter', counter);

if (repeat == false){
   counter++;
}

console.log('Counter', counter);
```

[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/kosona/edit?js,console)